# briefly holding shift+arrow results in "runaway" selection

Tags: keystrokes

When I try to select a region using shift+arrow, if I hold the key combination down for a second or two it will continue selecting the text after the keys are released.  It appears to enter an infinite loop and only stops after reaching the end (or beginning) of the buffer.

The arrow key alone does not show the same behavior.  This is reproducible across major modes.

Using GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) under WSL 1.

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you do see the same thing, and if you don't get more help here, you might want to file a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Do you have any accessibility features turned on? If you do, try turning them off.

Comment: Same behavior when I use the -Q flag.  I have not intentionally turned on any accessibility functions.

Comment: It looks like you (or someone else) filed Emacs bug [#49544](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=49544) for this.